# When I run "flutter run", I got follow error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio

This is my first post.
I just created a new project on flutter (the default app counter from flutter), then I installed the flutter packages.
[When I run flutter project, I've found following erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0RyA.png)

I think this is not important but I'd like to know the why.
Result is looks good.

If you have experience in this issue, please help me

Comment: Are you using Provider package by any chance?

Comment: well it seems your build worked well and you are only curious about that on line where it says an exception happened in Android folder,
to be able to assist you more please provide more info using flutter run -v and try to upload whole error log.